# Is there a way to execute a block of code during any uncaught exception?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I realize this is a shot in the dark and not the best practice or way of going about it, but I want to do specific logging information as the exception is thrown. It is important that the state of the web form does not change.

Comment: You can catch a generic exception

Comment: @JonathanO: OP mentioned in the title that he hasn't caught the exception.

Comment: I realize I can just catch the exception, but the situation I'm using it for must be for uncaught exceptions.

Comment: Global.asax, implement the  `Application_Error` method

Comment: In the post itself though, you say that you want to do the logging information "as the exception is caught". Are you catching it or not?

Comment: whoops, missed that error. The exception is uncaught, I changed the post to as the exception is thrown. Sorry about that.

Comment: Perhaps you should look at log4net, never used it myself but heard some good reviews.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
You can use 

    try
    {

    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
      //your treatment does not contain throw ex.
      //mute exception in order to not change state
    }

You can use this in your webform or in your gloabl.asax in Application_Error (in order to centralize exception treatment)
```

Comment: This should work, I didn't realize there was an Error event that's called in asp. Thanks!

Comment: I'am happy to help you tareqx3

Answer (score 1):

```
try
{
    ExceptionProneCode()
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    WriteToSomeLogFile(ex.Message);

    //if you want the exception to bubble up from this point, 
    //than you would type "throw;"
}
```

Comment: About the rethrow, it would be 'throw', not 'throw ex', you'll loose the stacktrace.

Answer (score 0):

If we are talking in the context of ASP.NET, the [Application_Error](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/24395wz3.aspx) event would be a good place to put a global exception logging block.